# Using Laravel's WhereIn to search multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, where-in

I have 3 SQL tables.

1. clients
2. events
3. client_events

Because a client can have multiple events, I made the third table to show those relationships. I am using the following code to retrieve all of the clients that have the have a record matching this event, but it is only returning 1 record when there are multiple.

```
$eventHosts = DB::table('clients')->whereIn('id', function($query) {
    $query->select('client_id')->from('client_events')->where('event_id', '=', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2]);
})->get();
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: You don't need to make a sub query, just make an array like this `DB::table('clients')->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4])->get();`

Comment: @sta the array is made up of results from a query

Comment: try Cameron Wilby answer, it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the ids first, then pass to the `whereIn` query.

```php
$clientIds = DB::table('client_events')
  ->where('event_id', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2])
  ->pluck('client_id')
  ->toArray();

$eventHosts = DB::table('clients')->whereIn('id', $clientIds)->get();
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but you missed a `get()` on last line

Answer (score 0):

To get the results in a single query and more efficeintly, try `join`

```php
$eventHosts = DB::table('clients') //select your main table
    ->join('client_events','client_events.client_id','=','clients.id') //join it on related columns
    ->where('client_events.client_id',explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2])) //apply your condition on client_events
    ->get();
```